# Middle Betti number bound of special $4$-manifolds

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds, 4-manifolds

I was thinking of the following question regarding $4$-manifolds as follows.

Let $M$ be a compact, oriented, smooth $4$-manifold with a smooth connected boundary, say $N$. Let $M$ be simply connected and $\pi_1(N)=G$, a finite group. Can we bound $b_2(M)$ (the second Betti-number of $M$) in terms of $|G|$ (cardinality of G)?

Of course, the answer to the above is not true as one can take connected sums with $(S^2\times S^2)$ and make the middle Betti number arbitrarily large. So my questions are,

1. If $(M,N)$ are as above and $M$ has the property that there are no copies of connected summands of $S^2\times S^2$ or (similar type of simply connected 4-manifolds which affects the middle Betti number) occur in $M$, can we say that $b_2(M)$ is bounded by some function of $|G|$?
2. Can one put some condition on the similar pair $(M,N)$ so that $b_2(M)$ is bounded by some function of $|G|$?

Any suggestions will be helpful.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: A hypersurface of degree d>3 in CP^3 is simply connected and has b_2 increasing with d. It cannot be decomposed as a connected sum because it's Kaehler with b^+ > 1 so its Donaldson invariants are nonzero (and you can cut out a ball to get N=S^3)

Comment: You could take connected sums with other simply connected four-manifolds with $b_2 > 0$, not just $S^2\times S^2$. Don't you want to rule them all out?

Comment: Yes, you are right. I have edited the question.

Comment: Did you understand the comment by Jonny Evans? There is a vast class of smooth closed simply-connected indecomposable 4-manifolds and there is no reasonable way to bound their 2nd Betti number.

Comment: If this is just curiosity-driven (as opposed to having some application in mind) then you might think about *lower* bounds on b_2 in the case that the fundamental group of M is a given group. In the closed case (or N=a 3-sphere) there is nice work on this by Hausmann-Weinberger and others.